# Connect to Heroku Postgres with Python and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

I want to connect my local python application to a Heroku postgres database. Actually, this case is nicely described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python):

```py
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

Looks quite easy. Unfortunately, I get an error message that I cannot interpret:

```
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute '_contextual_connect'
```

Is it a version problem? Do you have any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I use the standard way of `sqlalchemy` and adjust the database by adding `psycopg2` beforehand. Although I do not import `psycopg2`, it has to be installed in the environment.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://...')
```

Conclusion: Works for me!